"Infatuation" em português
Recentemente descobri a palavra "Infatuation".
O significado que encontrei é:
EN - Love reflects a deep connection, where infatuation is more of a surface level feeling. 
PT - "Love" reflete uma conexão profunda, enquanto a "infatuation" é mais um sentimento superficial.

O google tradutor ou DeepL apenas traduz "Infatuation" para "Paixão", mas como a palavra "Paixão" pode ser usada para significar "Love", queria saber se existia outra palavra mais específica que apenas se adeqúe à tradução de "Infatuation".
Se for à página da wikipédia da palavra é possível selecionar versões diferentes da mesma escritas numa linguagem diferente, no entanto não havia uma versão portuguesa. As versões da página que mais se assemelham ao português são as de espanhol e francês. Em espanhol, a palavra é "Infatuación" e em francês é "Entichement".
Queria também saber, não havendo uma tradução perfeita, se, por exemplo, ao escrever um livro, posso utilizar a palavra inglesa, espanhola ou francesa no seu lugar, e se encaixaria bem no resto do texto em português.

"Queria também saber, não havendo uma tradução perfeita, se, por exemplo, ao escrever um livro, posso utilizar a palavra inglesa, espanhola ou francesa no seu lugar, e se encaixaria bem no resto do texto em português". Existe alguma autoridade que prohibiria tal tolice?

Primeiramente, a definição dada de que «"Love" representa uma conexão profunda, enquanto "infatuation" é um sentimento mais superficial» não é acertada.
"Love" não representa necessariamente uma conexão profunda, embora amiúde seja o caso — isso se prova quando constatamos os nativos usando 'love' nos mais diversos contextos que nada de profundo involvam.
E "infatuation" não é um sentimento superficial nem fraco. O Dicionário Cambridge define a palavra como:

strong but not usually lasting feelings of love or attraction

O dicionário Google como:

an intense but short-lived passion or admiration for someone or something.

Ou seja, em relação ao sentimento o tempo é curto mas a substância é forte.
O tradutor do Cambridge traduz 'infatuation' como "paixão, fascinação, enrabichamento". Claramente não é uma boa tradução.
A tradução do Infopédia tampouco, pois traduz como "1. paixão 2. amor excessivo 3. entusiasmo absorvente".
Na minha opinião, a palavra com significado equivalente é a informal 'paixonite' — uma paixão pequena —, que bem se poderia usar em livros.
O infopédia traduz 'paixonite' como 'crush' ao inglês, mas acho que 'crush' se traduza melhor como 'queda (romântica)'. Convido os utentes portugueses a levantarem suas gírias também.
A palavra 'enfatuação' já existe e significa 'encher-se de vaidade'. Esse é o único significado factual e possível da palavra, pois eis: en+fatua+ação, de en+fatu-+ar, de 'fátuo', que significa vão, vaidade tola.
A palavra espanhola 'infatuación' também existe e nada tem a ver com amor; pelo contrário, tem basicamente o mesmo significado da palavra portuguesa — o autor dessa tradução errada cometeu o mesmo engano do tipo embaraçada ↔ embarazada. Afinal, que sentido faria uma palavra cuja raiz significa 'vão' ter algo a ver com amor?
A palavra francesa entichement também não traduz perfeitamente para infatuation. Infatuation é um amor curto e forte, entichement é uma paixão que surge repentinamente — não são bem a mesma coisa.
Como lição, vê-se que uma tradução perfeita na maioria das vezes não existe entre línguas geneticamente distantes (isto é, um significante não corresponde ao mesmo conjunto de significados). A frase "I am blonde" não permite a mesma distinção importantíssima que "Sou louro" e "Estou louro" mantêm, e ainda assim traduções ING-PT não inserem o verbo português em frases inglesas.

Queria também saber, não havendo uma tradução perfeita, se, por
exemplo, ao escrever um livro, posso utilizar a palavra inglesa,
espanhola ou francesa no seu lugar, e se encaixaria bem no resto do
texto em português.

Não. Em livros de Tolstói, grande parte de vários capítulos é em francês, mas isso porque os diálogos, dos nobres russos num período em que a língua de cultura era a francesa, são em francês — as personagens estão literalmente falando francês dentro de seu universo fictício. Usar uma palavra estrangeira por uma portuguesa para exprimir um significado qualquer na narração: primeiro, trai o leitor, o qual comprou o livro em e fala português e não outra língua, e, segundo, demonstra falta de domínio da língua em que se escreve por ter de se apelar a outra para se expressar.

He was infatuated with her.

Ele estava encantado com/por ela.
Ele estava obcecado com ela.
Ele sentia uma paixão passageira por ela.

Claro que não. Usa uma palavra de português. Nem entendo a pergunta. Porque um escritor brasileiro quer usar infatuation?
Esses tradutores automáticos são pêssimos para a literatura.
O Michaelis dá: obsessão, paixão passageira
Eu acho que também pode ser: encantamento, encantar
Será que já não se usa dicionários?
Se vê também: enrabichar ou enrabichamento

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
